# Symfony2/Doctrine - Disabling Softdeletable fiter only worked every other time

Tags: php, symfony, filter, doctrine, soft-delete

I'm using the Softdeleteable doctrine filter, however I have a method to remove all records from the database that should disable the filter before removing records.  It only seems to work every other time it's run though (once the records have deletedAt values).

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: toby
 * Date: 08/07/2014
 * Time: 17:29
 */

namespace Client\ComponentBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

abstract class BaseEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Attempts to delete all records from a table
     *
     * @param bool $bypassSoftDelete
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deleteAll( $bypassSoftDelete = false )
    {
        $softdeleteableFilter = 'softdeleteable';
        $filters              = $this->getEntityManager()->getFilters();

        if ($bypassSoftDelete && $filters->isEnabled( $softdeleteableFilter )) {
            $filters->disable( $softdeleteableFilter );
        }

        $entities = $this->findAll();
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->remove( $entity );
        }

        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

        if ($bypassSoftDelete) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->getFilters()->enable( $softdeleteableFilter );
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the softdeleteable filter only adds stuff into your query for selects and what not, so enabling and/or disabling it before a remove doesn't really do anything.

The reason you are needing to do the 2 attempts to delete anything is because of this...

<kbd>Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener</kbd>

```
/**
 * If it's a SoftDeleteable object, update the "deletedAt" field
 * and skip the removal of the object
 *
 * @param EventArgs $args
 * @return void
 */
public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
{
    //...

    //getScheduledDocumentDeletions
    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectDeletions($uow) as $object) {
        //...

        if (isset($config['softDeleteable']) && $config['softDeleteable']) {

            $reflProp = $meta->getReflectionProperty($config['fieldName']);
            $oldValue = $reflProp->getValue($object);

            <!-- THIS BIT -->
            if ($oldValue instanceof \Datetime) {
                continue; // want to hard delete
            }

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that decides whether or not the object actually gets deleted is if it has been "softdeleted" previously. This mean that no matter what you do with the filter, the listener will first softdelete, followed by a hard delete on the next pass.

I guess the easiest way to get around this would be to set a date for your `deletedAt` (or your deletedAt field) prior to flushing the actual remove.

**Extra Info**

The ORM doesn't directly perform a DELETE operation that is replaced with an UPDATE.

When you remove a model the ORM schedules it for deletion, this is then intercepted by the listener and then persisted again with the updated deletedAt field set.

Assuming your `fieldName` is set to `deletedAt`

<kbd>Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener</kbd>

```
public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
{
    //..

    // Get all entities that are scheduled for deletion
    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectDeletions($uow) as $object) {
        // Check softdeleteable is enabled for model
        if (isset($config['softDeleteable']) && $config['softDeleteable']) {
            // Get current value of deletedAt
            $reflProp = $meta->getReflectionProperty($config['fieldName']);
            $oldValue = $reflProp->getValue($object);

            // If deletedAt is already set, drop out of update process,
            // otherwise continue on with "softdelete"
            if ($oldValue instanceof \Datetime) {
                continue; // want to hard delete
            }

            // Dispatch "PRE_SOFT_DELETE" event
            $evm->dispatchEvent(
                self::PRE_SOFT_DELETE,
                $ea->createLifecycleEventArgsInstance($object, $om)
            );

            // Set deletedAt field to now
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $reflProp->setValue($object, $date);

            // Persist model and schedule for extra update, moving 
            // model from "scheduledForDeletion" to "scheduledForUpdate"
            $om->persist($object);
            $uow->propertyChanged($object, $config['fieldName'], $oldValue, $date);
            $uow->scheduleExtraUpdate($object, array(
                $config['fieldName'] => array($oldValue, $date)
            ));

            // Dispatch "POST_SOFT_DELETE" event
            $evm->dispatchEvent(
                self::POST_SOFT_DELETE,
                $ea->createLifecycleEventArgsInstance($object, $om)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice... but surely it adds stuff when removing using remove() too, as it intercepts the DELETE operation on such requests & replaces them with an UPDATE with the deletedAt value?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It doesn't directly perform a `DELETE` operation that is replaced with an `UPDATE`. When you remove a model the ORM schedules it for deletion, this is then intercepted by the listener and then persisted again with the updated `deletedAt` field set. See my answer for more on this..

Comment: Ah, so disabling the filter does not stop the listener performing the soft delete then?  Get it now.  A little more research lead me to this post about how to actually get this to work as I wanted... http://bit.ly/1rrFXuL